# Highchart ID does not update with new variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I try to generate a windrose on my website using highcharts. It should display the direction with an arrow and the speed in the gauge itself.

I have the following code to generate the charts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
\\ some other parameters not relating to question
series: [{
        data: [{
                id: 'wnddr',
                y: winddir,
                dial: {
                        radius: '90%',
                        baseWidth: 3,
                        baseLength: '95%',
                        rearLength: 0
                }
        }],
        dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter : function(){
                        return windspd + ' km/u';
                }
        }
}]
},

function (chart){
        setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "example.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cahce: "false",
        success: function(data){
        windspd = data.query.results.channel.wind.speed;
        winddir = data.query.results.channel.wind.direction;
        windchill = data.query.results.channel.wind.chill;
        hum = data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity;
        druk = data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.pressure;
        ss = data.query.results.channel.astronomy.sunset;
        sr = data.query.results.channel.astronomy.sunrise;
        temp = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        des = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[0].code;
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        point.update(winddir);
//      alert(winddir);
}
});
$('.update').html("<img src=http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/" +des+ ".gif />");
}, 5000);
});
});
```

With `wnddr.update(winddir);` I was trying to update the winddir-variable in my chart. However, I can't get it to work. Also the alert does not pop-up so probably my code gets stuck just before. If I comment the two line above the alert out, the alert will work. Same goes for the speed-variable. Problem here is that is doesn't have a id-attribute.
I modified the code from [highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/3CUgG/) as the basis. Giving 'y' a value by hand generates a valid and correct gauge. The same goes for a fixed value of winddir.

Comment: `var wnddr = chart.get(wnddr);` -- you are trying to get null here, since the variable isn't set...? Also, checking console and telling what's in there might help.

Comment: It looks like `getData6` can't get the chart-variable. I modified the code in the OP. At least the wind speed works now but the wind direction still isn't going anywhere...

Comment: After a day of struggling I found I had to use `chart.series[0].data[0].update(winddir);
`

Comment: Would there be a way that this script is executed straight away after a page load?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. I would say that a couple of ways :) Personally, I would create a function which you have in the callback. Then do something like that: `function(chart) { updateChart(chart); setInterval(function() { updateChart(chart); }, 5000); });` And `updateChart(chart)`will be that created function.